# Visual Studio Online - The version descriptor <BranchName> could not be resolved

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I am working on a project with visual studio online and git.

I tried accessing the TFS Online web site and openning the source code of the project I am working on and I found this error popping up absolutely everywhere:

TF401175:The version descriptor Branch could not be resolved to a version in the repository ProjectName

I can't access the branches, commits, source code or absolutely anything.
The other team members don't have the problem, and it seems to be tied to my account, seeing as I tried openning it on another device with my account and still failed.

All operations from visual studio work fine. I can commit, pull, push, etc. I only can't access the Web Panel. Tried googling for the error but all I found was the bug reported on the MS site, which was closed and said that the problem is fixed. Doesn't seem fixed to me.

Comment: Is it defaulting to a deleted branch maybe? Can you tell from the URL? Does anyone else access the repo, does out work for them?

Comment: @DaveShaw It works for the rest of the team. I am the only one it doesn't work for. And yes it is refering to a deleted branch, one that nobody else has or is able to see any longer.

Comment: Can you change the branch name in the URL to a working one? Maybe get someone to click on a working branch on their machine then copy that one onto yours? This is the "query" on my repo for master: `#path=%2F&version=GBmaster&_a=contents` (paste it after the repo name in the URL).

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing what you said and the everything was working again, then I realized that that is the default branch for me and it no longer exists, so I went into Code/Explorer and simply selected the master branch. I feel dumb, but this is a problem that isn't supposed to exist. Post this comment as an answer and I will accept :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your default branch has been deleted.

You need to change your default branch to one that exists. Try using the branch selector, it that's not available, try appending `#path=%2F&version=GBmaster&_a=contents` to the end of the default "Code" URL.

Comment: Was exactly my issue, a bit of a different scenario. Release pipeline never triggered , but was set to be triggered for a new build of a specific build pipeline I was in. I checked the release pipeline and one of the build artifacts had the error op was talking about "The version descriptor <BranchName> could not be resolved" so I fixed branch to the correct default one (a non-existant one was set) and everything seems good

Comment: @DaveShaw How may I change the default branch? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I could resolve this error in PR by selecting valid branch names, something like development into master.  I was getting this error because there was a default selection 
 master into main. and in my case main branch was not exist. I changed that to development to master. then it started working.

Answer (score 4):

I've had this issue for a long time.  We migrated code into a new repo and then deleted the primary branch.  Every time we made a pull request we got this error.  I finally figured out how to solve it:

1. Go to your Branches page.
2. Pick any branch other than your current default branch and click on the 'More Options' dots.
3. Set this branch as the 'Compare' branch.
4. Pick the branch you want to be the default PR branch and click on the 'More Options' dots.
5. Set this branch as the 'Compare' branch.

This link clued me in on this solution:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/the-default-branch-wont-be-default-item-of-target/200210

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. 
In my case my **local branch had not yet been synced to the server**, so in my web browser the Pull-Request was on the server (vsts) but my branch was not. 
**To fix it:** I did a Sync in VS, pushed my local branch, then it worked: I refreshed the Pull Request in the browser and then the error disappeared.

Comment: I had the same issue as above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I tried to get file contents and got eventually the same error.

> TF401174: The item 'item' could not be found in the repository 'repository'  at the version specified by 'Branch:' (resolved to commit 'commit')'

I was trying to make if from the the VisualStudioOnline libs (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Client, Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client)

```
VssBasicCredential credintials = new VssBasicCredential(String.Empty, "YOUR SECRET CODE HERE");
VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri("https://yourserverurl.visualstudio.com/"), credintials);
GitHttpClient client = connection.GetClient<GitHttpClient>();

List<GitRepository> repositories = await client.GetRepositoriesAsync(true); // or use GetRepositoryAsync()
var repo = repositories.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "Some.Repo.Name");

GitVersionDescriptor descriptor = new GitVersionDescriptor()
{
    VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch,
    Version = "develop",
    VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
};

List<GitItem> items = await client.GetItemsAsync(repo.Id, scopePath: "/", recursionLevel: VersionControlRecursionType.Full, versionDescriptor: descriptor);
```

Then if you will try directly to get contents of an item `client.GetItemTextAsync(repo.Id, item.Path)` you will receive such kind of error in case when the branch isn't default. Just provide GitVersionDescriptior again.

```
GitVersionDescriptor commitDescriptior = new GitVersionDescriptor()
{
    VersionType = GitVersionType.Commit,
    Version = item.CommitId,
    VersionOptions = GitVersionOptions.None
};

Stream stream = await client.GetItemTextAsync(repo.Id, item.Path, download: true, versionDescriptor: commitDescriptior)
```

Answer (score 0):

In our team's case, we got this error when we tried to create Pull Requests in the Azure Devops UI.

We think we got this error because our branch names typically have forward slash characters in the name, e.g.

`peter/bugfix/BF123-fix-surname-width-issue`

When attempting to create a PR for a branch named like that, the error would include each  `/` having been converted to ASCII, so:

`peter%2Fbugfix%2FBF123-fix-surname-width-issue`

Our fix was to select the branch from the branch selector on the same page as the error message, (which was correctly shown with the `/` characters rather than ASCII) and continue creating our PR.